# google cloud vision ocr でテキストレイアウト出力(hocr)する方法

Tags: google-cloud

google cloud vision のOCRの認識精度が高いのでこれを使ってテキスト検索可能なpdfを作れないかと思っています。

google cloud vision ocr の出力には文字の位置情報が含まれているようなので、これをhocrに変換するスクリプト等ありましたら教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: こちらでも議論しています。https://github.com/tmbdev/hocr-tools/issues/26

Comment: GitHubでGoogle Cloud Vision OCRからhocrへの変換プログラムを公開しました。

https://github.com/dinosauria123/gcv2hocr

まだバグだらけですが付属のサンプルではある程度変換できます。
日本語はまだダメです。